# merge where alternative and multiple conditions

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So as far as I can tell, it is not possible to use where in a merge statement. Then how do I do multiple conditions?

What I want to achieve, but cannot work:

```
MERGE (n:Node) 
WHERE n.key = "test1" OR n.key = "test2"
ON CREATE n.key = "test1"
return n
```

So how do I create an or condition on my merge statement? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

It does not look like MERGE supports the WHERE clause. However, you *can* specify ONE test value per property; for example:

```
MERGE (n:Node {key:'test1'})
RETURN n;
```

In your case, since you want to test for multiple values per property, there is no way to do that with MERGE

Also, if I understand what you are trying to do, it does not look like MERGE was the right thing to use anyway. I think the following Cypher code should give you the results that you are looking for:

```
MATCH (n:Node { key: "test1" })
RETURN n
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Node { key: 'test2' })
SET n.key = 'test1'
RETURN n;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you would deal with the condition that you already have two nodes, one with `test1` and another one with `test2` in your graph. You would have to merge the two nodes, e.g. also moving the relationships from test2 to test1.

In general I'd try something like this (like cybersam suggested):

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Node { key: 'test2' })
SET n.key = 'test1'
MERGE (m:Node { key: "test1" })
RETURN m
```